# select and deselect check on listgrid

Tags: smartgwt

I get the next code a listgrid with the firs column is a check:

```
private ListGrid listGrid = new ListGrid();
....
....
listGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
    listGrid .addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            //TODO
        }
    });
```

I would like select or deselect the check component on my listgrid on the fly when a row is clicked.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to search if your requirement can be fulfilled by some API functionality but couldn't find so.

So I've implemented this behavior programmatically. Please try the following code:

```
grid.addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event) {
            ListGridRecord record = (ListGridRecord) event.getRecord();
            ListGridRecord[] selectedRecords = grid.getSelectedRecords();
            if (selectedRecords != null) {
                List<ListGridRecord> selectedRecordsList = Arrays.asList(selectedRecords);
                if (selectedRecordsList.contains(record)) {
                    // the record is already selected, so deselect it.
                    grid.deselectRecord(record);
                } else {
                    // the record is already deselected, so select it.
                    grid.selectRecord(record);
                }
            } else {
                // the record is already deselected, so select it.
                grid.selectRecord(record);
            }
        }
});
```

Here **grid** is an instance of `ListGrid`.

Comment: one line `grid.selectRecord(record, !grid.isSelected(record));`